# Google Appointments in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins

I am looking for a way to integrate google appointments with wordpress. How can I make it so a user can come to my site and see a block of time and make an appointment with me via google appointments?

Answer (score 1):

Although not a plugin, an easy solution I have used in the past is to create a new static page and in the HTML editor, followed the instructions for http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=41207

You could also follow those instructions for inserting into a theme directly (say, in a side-bar).

Edit: This was for showing off to my client what times I'm already booked (Following the embed tutorial on that link, clients could see what times were already booked but not the actual details).  Clients would then use a contact form below requesting the date and time.  I believe I used http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ for the form with custom options.